# Converting DateTime to String in a SQL Select statement to format correct DateTime in SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am inserting data into a SQL Server table through a controller in my ASP.NET MVC project. I need to know how to format a DateTime to a string so that SQL Server will display it correctly.

This is the code I am working with

```
var queryable = ((IQueryable<PoScenarioQueueManager>)filters.ApplyTo(query)).ApplyCustomFilters();

var sql = queryable.ToParameterizedQuery();
var declaration = sql.Substring(0, sql.IndexOf("SELECT", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
var select = sql.Replace(declaration, "");
var statement = "@Declaration " +
                            "INSERT INTO dbo.ScenarioQueues (ScenarioUserId, ScenarioTypeId, ScenarioId" +
                            ", VendorNumber, VendorName, DepartmentNumber, DepartmentName, AuditReleaseId, ItemId, ItemNumber" +
                            ", ItemUpc, BeginDate, EndDate, PaidCost, NewCost, ImportItemsFilePath" +
                            ", ExportItemsFilePath, ScenarioSource, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy" +
                            ", CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, PoEvent, PoEventId, CheckStartDate, CheckEndDate)" +
                            "SELECT ScenarioUserId, ScenarioTypeId, ScenarioId, VendorNumber, VendorName" +
                            ", DepartmentNumber, DepartmentName, AuditReleaseId, ItemId, ItemNumber, ItemUpc" +
                            ", BeginDate, EndDate, PaidCost, NewCost, ImportItemsFilePath, ExportItemsFilePath" +
                            ", ScenarioSource, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, PoEvent" +
                            ", PoEventId, "+currentAuditstartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ", "+currentAuditendDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")+ 
                            " FROM ( @Select ) As QUERY";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(entities.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement.Replace("@Declaration", declaration).Replace("@Select", select), connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The table in SQL Server is not showing the correct `DateTime` format. The `currentAuditstartDate` and `currentAuditendDate` are the ones that are not being passed correctly in order for SQL Server to show the correct DateTime format.

Comment: You should be parametrising your statement, not injecting values. And date & time datatypes don't have a "format", they are stored as a binary value. It's up to the presentation layer on how to display the value, not SQL Server,

Comment: quick answer - 'yyyyMMdd' (in single quotes) e.g '20020911' is an ISO format - very reliable

Comment: Also, as you write it now, Sql Server sees a subtraction operation, not a date 2019-06-25 = 1988

Comment: Take this [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c99556553f22e5ce73306390aa0728e) for example. Every string literal is different, however, the end result is the same for every value. in this case, DB Fiddle chooses to use the display format (for me) of `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Which, to add to the comment by @Steve would be seen as the `datetime` `1905-06-12 00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var statement = "@Declaration " +
                        "INSERT INTO dbo.ScenarioQueues (ScenarioUserId, ScenarioTypeId, ScenarioId" +
                        ", VendorNumber, VendorName, DepartmentNumber, DepartmentName, AuditReleaseId, ItemId, ItemNumber" +
                        ", ItemUpc, BeginDate, EndDate, PaidCost, NewCost, ImportItemsFilePath" +
                        ", ExportItemsFilePath, ScenarioSource, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy" +
                        ", CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, PoEvent, PoEventId, CheckStartDate, CheckEndDate)" +
                        "SELECT ScenarioUserId, ScenarioTypeId, ScenarioId, VendorNumber, VendorName" +
                        ", DepartmentNumber, DepartmentName, AuditReleaseId, ItemId, ItemNumber, ItemUpc" +
                        ", BeginDate, EndDate, PaidCost, NewCost, ImportItemsFilePath, ExportItemsFilePath" +
                        ", ScenarioSource, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, PoEvent" +
                        ", PoEventId, '" + currentAuditstartDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "', '" + currentAuditendDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") +
                        "' FROM ( @Select ) As QUERY";
```

'yyyyMMdd' (in single quotes) e.g '20020911' is an ISO format - very reliable

Comment: Why not just properly parametrise the query? Then the format is the string doesn't matter, as the datatype is correct.

Comment: @Cato - Thank you very much. Just what I needed.